# GNU screen: how to check current scrollback value?

Tags: gnu-screen

In GNU screen, I know that I can change the scrollback (buffer size) using this command:

`<Ctrl-a>:scrollback 10000`

as well as adding this line in `.screenrc`:

`defscrollback 10000`

But How do I check what the current value is? (For clarification, looking at the `.screenrc` file and locating the line with `defscrollback` is not the solution I'm looking for.)

Thanks!

Comment: this likely belongs on superuser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As soon as you enter scrollback mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd>), you should see a status line like

```
Copy mode - Column 71 Line 25(+3000) (80,25)
```

The 3000 is the scrollback size. As long as you're in scrollback mode, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to see a shorter version of that status line. If you're no longer at the bottom, the +3000 will be changed to show how far you've scrolled back. It tells how many lines are available above the currently displayed region, so +0 means you've scrolled back all the way.

Comment: Good solution, but the downside seems that I first need to fully fill the buffer before I can get the correct `scrollback` value.

Comment: Maybe this is version-dependent, but for me it always shows the full value (and if I scroll back past the beginning of the session, I see 3000 blank lines)

Comment: I stand corrected! Thanks for helping me realize that haha.

Comment: The `Ctrl G` to see if I am in `Copy mode` was just what I was looking for.

Comment: @TonyBarganski I agree that ctrl+g in copy mode is amazing the scrollback kept disappearing and i needed to count the 0s i had set lol.

Answer (score 5):

You can also issue the command `Ctrl-A i` to get the value of the scrollback size currently set for that particular window.